# PHP Script Query to filter results in link

Tags: php, sql, filter, hyperlink, where-clause

I have a SQL database with all my customer tickets that i access trough this link to show ALL tickets from selected customer:

`...pull.php?user=customer`

and with this query:

```
$query2x = 'SELECT * FROM `client_invoices` WHERE `username` = \'' . $user . '\' ORDER BY date_due ASC LIMIT ' . $i . ',' . $v;
```

I have 5 distinct ticket states, and i need to filter the above results by states, possibly in the link, like this:

`...pull.php?user=customer&state=entry`
`...pull.php?user=customer&state=due`
etc...

but if i add

```
`state` = \'' . $state. '\'
```

to the query this is possible but cant find a way to present all tickets in all states...

Any ideas to achieve this?

Thanks,
Sandro

Comment: 1. You are wide open to SQL injection attack with this code. Please learn about parameterized queries (the details can vary depending on which driver for which DBMS you are using). 2. Can't you just use an **if** block to query with or without the **state** part of the **WHERE** clause depending on whether there is a state included in the request?

Comment: Can you give me an example about the IF block?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.phphttps://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php